# Equal border-left and border-right height in CSS

Tags: css, border

[image]
[image]

How can I make border-left the same height as border-right? In other words, how to change the order of the borders? Border-left is taller than border-right. Which results in a 1px "gap".

```
.tab-header > ul > li
{
display: inline-block;
background-color: #ffffff;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
border-left: 1px solid #cecece;
border-right: 1px solid #cecece;
border-top: 1px solid #cecece;
padding: 8px;
font-size: 10px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening, is that the css tries to make a nice diagonal colour change in the border. If you change all the `1px` to `10px`, you see the problem. (Image, see: http://jsfiddle.net/DaTCy/1/)

[image]

If you are using 1px widths of the borders, the bottom and the right border will always overlap in the bottom-right pixel.

---

EDIT: As a solution, you can try giving the bottom border a width of 0px, and solving the height problem in the container you put the button in.

Comment: You're right. But do you have any solutions/alternatives? I don't want use 2px.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to explicitly use:

```
border-bottom-width: 0;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/M2bWa/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `border-left/-top/-right` and `border-bottom` for *different* [nested] elements.